# How do I/where do I put a custom Animated Floating Action Button to be on top of the main page/content? flutter

Tags: flutter, button, action, floating

I have followed a couple of tutorials on creating a custom floating action button and have successfully recreated it and customized to my liking. BUT, I am experiencing a beginner issue, whereas I cannot figure out how to/where start building the main body of content.

To be more specific, I want to build a video feed (like an instagram/youtube style), but have the FAB (floating action button) as the menu which will be available on this and a few other screens.

**How do I/where in the code do I start to build my main body of content?**

Please find my current code below for the custom action button and animation. Thanks for your time.

```
import 'dart:ui';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/painting.dart';
import 'constants.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Mandaboo',
      theme: ThemeData(

      ),
      home: MyHomePage(
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {

  AnimationController animationController;
  Animation degOneTranslationAnimation,degTwoTranslationAnimation,degThreeTranslationAnimation, degFourTranslationAnimation;
  Animation rotationAnimation;


  double getRadiansFromDegree(double degree) {
    double unitRadian = 57.295779513;
    return degree / unitRadian;
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    animationController = AnimationController(vsync: this,duration: Duration(milliseconds: 250));
    degOneTranslationAnimation = TweenSequence([
      TweenSequenceItem<double>(tween: Tween<double >(begin: 0.0,end: 1.2), weight: 75.0),
      TweenSequenceItem<double>(tween: Tween<double>(begin: 1.2,end: 1.0), weight: 25.0),
    ]).animate(animationController);
    degTwoTranslationAnimation = TweenSequence([
      TweenSequenceItem<double>(tween: Tween<double >(begin: 0.0,end: 1.4), weight: 55.0),
      TweenSequenceItem<double>(tween: Tween<double>(begin: 1.4,end: 1.0), weight: 45.0),
    ]).animate(animationController);
    degThreeTranslationAnimation = TweenSequence([
      TweenSequenceItem<double>(tween: Tween<double >(begin: 0.0,end: 1.75), weight: 35.0),
      TweenSequenceItem<double>(tween: Tween<double>(begin: 1.75,end: 1.0), weight: 65.0),
    ]).animate(animationController);
    degFourTranslationAnimation = TweenSequence([
      TweenSequenceItem<double>(tween: Tween<double >(begin: 0.0,end: 2.10), weight: 15.0),
      TweenSequenceItem<double>(tween: Tween<double>(begin: 2.10,end: 1.0), weight: 85.0),
    ]).animate(animationController);
    rotationAnimation = Tween<double>(begin: 180.0,end: 0.0).animate(CurvedAnimation(parent: animationController
        , curve: Curves.easeOut));
    super.initState();
    animationController.addListener((){
      setState(() {

      });
    });
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return Container(
      child: Scaffold(
          body: Container(
            width: size.width,
            height: size.height,
            child: Stack(
              children: <Widget>[
                Positioned(
                    right: 30,
                    bottom: 30,
                    child: Stack(
                      alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        IgnorePointer(
                          child: Container(
                            color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.0), // comment or change to transparent color
                            height: 150.0,
                            width: 150.0,
                          ),
                        ),
                        Transform.translate(
                          offset: Offset.fromDirection(getRadiansFromDegree(270),degOneTranslationAnimation.value * 100),
                          child: Transform(
                            transform: Matrix4.rotationZ(getRadiansFromDegree(rotationAnimation.value))..scale(degOneTranslationAnimation.value),
                            alignment: Alignment.center,
                            child: CircularButton(
                              color: Colors.red,
                              width: 40,
                              height: 40,
                              icon: Icon(
                                Icons.add,
                                color: Colors.white,
                              ),
                              onClick: (){
                                print('First Button');
                              },
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Transform.translate(
                          offset: Offset.fromDirection(getRadiansFromDegree(240),degTwoTranslationAnimation.value * 100),
                          child: Transform(
                            transform: Matrix4.rotationZ(getRadiansFromDegree(rotationAnimation.value))..scale(degTwoTranslationAnimation.value),
                            alignment: Alignment.center,
                            child: CircularButton(
                              color: Colors.black54,
                              width: 40,
                              height: 40,
                              icon: Icon(
                                Icons.shop_two,
                                color: Colors.white,
                              ),
                              onClick: (){
                                print('Second button');
                              },
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Transform.translate(
                          offset: Offset.fromDirection(getRadiansFromDegree(210),degThreeTranslationAnimation.value * 100),
                          child: Transform(
                            transform: Matrix4.rotationZ(getRadiansFromDegree(rotationAnimation.value))..scale(degThreeTranslationAnimation.value),
                            alignment: Alignment.center,
                            child: CircularButton(
                              color: Colors.black54,
                              width: 40,
                              height: 40,
                              icon: Icon(
                                Icons.equalizer,
                                color: Colors.white,
                              ),
                              onClick: (){
                                print('Third Button');
                              },
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Transform.translate(
                          offset: Offset.fromDirection(getRadiansFromDegree(180),degFourTranslationAnimation.value * 100),
                          child: Transform(
                            transform: Matrix4.rotationZ(getRadiansFromDegree(rotationAnimation.value))..scale(degFourTranslationAnimation.value),
                            alignment: Alignment.center,
                            child: CircularButton(
                              color: Colors.black54,
                              width: 40,
                              height: 40,
                              icon: Icon(
                                Icons.settings,
                                color: Colors.white,
                              ),
                              onClick: (){
                                print('Fourth Button');
                              },
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Transform(
                          transform: Matrix4.rotationZ(getRadiansFromDegree(rotationAnimation.value)),
                          alignment: Alignment.center,
                          child: CircularButton(
                            color: Colors.red,
                            width: 60,
                            height: 60,
                            icon: Icon(
                              Icons.menu,
                              color: Colors.white,
                            ),
                            onClick: (){
                              if (animationController.isCompleted) {
                                animationController.reverse();
                              } else {
                                animationController.forward();
                              }
                            },
                          ),
                        )

                      ],
                    ))
              ],
            ),
          ),

      ),
    );
  }
}


class CircularButton extends StatelessWidget {

  final double width;
  final double height;
  final Color color;
  final Icon icon;
  final Function onClick;

  CircularButton({this.color, this.width, this.height, this.icon, this.onClick});


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(color: color,shape: BoxShape.circle),
      width: width,
      height: height,
      child: IconButton(icon: icon,enableFeedback: true, onPressed: onClick),
    );
  }
}
```

p.s - I realize there is likely a very simple answer to this, but it's eluding me right now.
p.p.s - I have done some serious searches for this, but couldn't find an answer, hence the question.

Comment: I didn't get your question. Are you asking where to place the above custom floating action button code ?

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying. I need to know where to put that block of code yes. I have tried putting a container widget and center/text widget etc above and below that block of code but nothing shows up in the white background space.

Comment: keep the code in a stateless or stateful widget and pass the widget as the floatingActionbutton attribute of the scaffold

Comment: what do mean by nothing shows up ? Is it your floating action button is not visible ?

Comment: Thanks so much for your help so far! :) It's the opposite actually. The action button is perfect, it's there and the animations etc work great. My issue is, I cannot figure out how to put the content behind it. So, FAB has no problems. I just need to know where/which line/how to start building my main content (the content the FAB floats in front of)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

content was not visible as you were using scaffold for your custom FAB

```
import 'dart:ui';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/painting.dart';
//import 'constants.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Mandaboo',
      theme: ThemeData(

      ),
      home: MyHomePage(
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(child: Text('hi i\'m content'),),
        floatingActionButton: CustomFAB(),
    );
  }
}


class CustomFAB extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CustomFABState createState() => _CustomFABState();
}

class _CustomFABState extends State<CustomFAB> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {

  AnimationController animationController;
  Animation degOneTranslationAnimation,degTwoTranslationAnimation,degThreeTranslationAnimation, degFourTranslationAnimation;
  Animation rotationAnimation;


  double getRadiansFromDegree(double degree) {
    double unitRadian = 57.295779513;
    return degree / unitRadian;
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    animationController = AnimationController(vsync: this,duration: Duration(milliseconds: 250));
    degOneTranslationAnimation = TweenSequence([
      TweenSequenceItem<double>(tween: Tween<double >(begin: 0.0,end: 1.2), weight: 75.0),
      TweenSequenceItem<double>(tween: Tween<double>(begin: 1.2,end: 1.0), weight: 25.0),
    ]).animate(animationController);
    degTwoTranslationAnimation = TweenSequence([
      TweenSequenceItem<double>(tween: Tween<double >(begin: 0.0,end: 1.4), weight: 55.0),
      TweenSequenceItem<double>(tween: Tween<double>(begin: 1.4,end: 1.0), weight: 45.0),
    ]).animate(animationController);
    degThreeTranslationAnimation = TweenSequence([
      TweenSequenceItem<double>(tween: Tween<double >(begin: 0.0,end: 1.75), weight: 35.0),
      TweenSequenceItem<double>(tween: Tween<double>(begin: 1.75,end: 1.0), weight: 65.0),
    ]).animate(animationController);
    degFourTranslationAnimation = TweenSequence([
      TweenSequenceItem<double>(tween: Tween<double >(begin: 0.0,end: 2.10), weight: 15.0),
      TweenSequenceItem<double>(tween: Tween<double>(begin: 2.10,end: 1.0), weight: 85.0),
    ]).animate(animationController);
    rotationAnimation = Tween<double>(begin: 180.0,end: 0.0).animate(CurvedAnimation(parent: animationController
        , curve: Curves.easeOut));
    super.initState();
    animationController.addListener((){
      setState(() {

      });
    });
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return Container(
      width: size.width,
      height: size.height,
      child: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          Positioned(
              right: 30,
              bottom: 30,
              child: Stack(
                alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
                children: <Widget>[
                  IgnorePointer(
                    child: Container(
                      color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.0), // comment or change to transparent color
                      height: 150.0,
                      width: 150.0,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Transform.translate(
                    offset: Offset.fromDirection(getRadiansFromDegree(270),degOneTranslationAnimation.value * 100),
                    child: Transform(
                      transform: Matrix4.rotationZ(getRadiansFromDegree(rotationAnimation.value))..scale(degOneTranslationAnimation.value),
                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                      child: CircularButton(
                        color: Colors.red,
                        width: 40,
                        height: 40,
                        icon: Icon(
                          Icons.add,
                          color: Colors.white,
                        ),
                        onClick: (){
                          print('First Button');
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Transform.translate(
                    offset: Offset.fromDirection(getRadiansFromDegree(240),degTwoTranslationAnimation.value * 100),
                    child: Transform(
                      transform: Matrix4.rotationZ(getRadiansFromDegree(rotationAnimation.value))..scale(degTwoTranslationAnimation.value),
                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                      child: CircularButton(
                        color: Colors.black54,
                        width: 40,
                        height: 40,
                        icon: Icon(
                          Icons.shop_two,
                          color: Colors.white,
                        ),
                        onClick: (){
                          print('Second button');
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Transform.translate(
                    offset: Offset.fromDirection(getRadiansFromDegree(210),degThreeTranslationAnimation.value * 100),
                    child: Transform(
                      transform: Matrix4.rotationZ(getRadiansFromDegree(rotationAnimation.value))..scale(degThreeTranslationAnimation.value),
                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                      child: CircularButton(
                        color: Colors.black54,
                        width: 40,
                        height: 40,
                        icon: Icon(
                          Icons.equalizer,
                          color: Colors.white,
                        ),
                        onClick: (){
                          print('Third Button');
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Transform.translate(
                    offset: Offset.fromDirection(getRadiansFromDegree(180),degFourTranslationAnimation.value * 100),
                    child: Transform(
                      transform: Matrix4.rotationZ(getRadiansFromDegree(rotationAnimation.value))..scale(degFourTranslationAnimation.value),
                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                      child: CircularButton(
                        color: Colors.black54,
                        width: 40,
                        height: 40,
                        icon: Icon(
                          Icons.settings,
                          color: Colors.white,
                        ),
                        onClick: (){
                          print('Fourth Button');
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Transform(
                    transform: Matrix4.rotationZ(getRadiansFromDegree(rotationAnimation.value)),
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    child: CircularButton(
                      color: Colors.red,
                      width: 60,
                      height: 60,
                      icon: Icon(
                        Icons.menu,
                        color: Colors.white,
                      ),
                      onClick: (){
                        if (animationController.isCompleted) {
                          animationController.reverse();
                        } else {
                          animationController.forward();
                        }
                      },
                    ),
                  )

                ],
              ))
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}


class CircularButton extends StatelessWidget {

  final double width;
  final double height;
  final Color color;
  final Icon icon;
  final Function onClick;

  CircularButton({this.color, this.width, this.height, this.icon, this.onClick});


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(color: color,shape: BoxShape.circle),
      width: width,
      height: height,
      child: IconButton(icon: icon,enableFeedback: true, onPressed: onClick),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Try this, the content is visible

Comment: Of course! Niteesh, you are an absolute star. Thanks so much! Silly me.

Comment: @nerdMonkey glad to help. You can tick the answer if it solved your query

Answer (score 0):

assuming this is your widget tree [image: benzneststudios.com img]
to create main content body go through [flutter codelabs](https://flutter.dev/docs/codelabs)

some pointers

- The Scaffold widget, from the Material library, provides a default app bar, a title, and a body property that holds the widget tree for the home screen. The widget subtree can be quite complex.
- A widget's main job is to provide a build method that describes how to display the widget in terms of other, lower-level widgets.

then to add a custom floatingaction button all you need to do is

```
...
Scaffold(
body: Center(..
floatingActionButton:MyCustomFaB(),
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply, this code doesn't actually use the floating action button widget. So I am lost in a sea of confusion.

Comment: go through the codelabs in answer and then update your question as its not clear

Answer (score 0):

You can copy paste run full code below 
You can move your custom `Floating Action Button` to `floatingActionButton` of `Scaffold` and put your main content in `body`

```
return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Test page'),
      ),
      body: ListView.separated(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
        itemCount: 50,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return Container(
            height: 50,
            color: Colors.blue,
            child: Center(child: Text('Entry ${index}')),
          );
        },
        separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) => const Divider(),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          Positioned(
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'dart:ui';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/painting.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Mandaboo',
      theme: ThemeData(),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  AnimationController animationController;
  Animation degOneTranslationAnimation,
      degTwoTranslationAnimation,
      degThreeTranslationAnimation,
      degFourTranslationAnimation;
  Animation rotationAnimation;

  double getRadiansFromDegree(double degree) {
    double unitRadian = 57.295779513;
    return degree / unitRadian;
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    animationController =
        AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: Duration(milliseconds: 250));
    degOneTranslationAnimation = TweenSequence([
      TweenSequenceItem<double>(
          tween: Tween<double>(begin: 0.0, end: 1.2), weight: 75.0),
      TweenSequenceItem<double>(
          tween: Tween<double>(begin: 1.2, end: 1.0), weight: 25.0),
    ]).animate(animationController);
    degTwoTranslationAnimation = TweenSequence([
      TweenSequenceItem<double>(
          tween: Tween<double>(begin: 0.0, end: 1.4), weight: 55.0),
      TweenSequenceItem<double>(
          tween: Tween<double>(begin: 1.4, end: 1.0), weight: 45.0),
    ]).animate(animationController);
    degThreeTranslationAnimation = TweenSequence([
      TweenSequenceItem<double>(
          tween: Tween<double>(begin: 0.0, end: 1.75), weight: 35.0),
      TweenSequenceItem<double>(
          tween: Tween<double>(begin: 1.75, end: 1.0), weight: 65.0),
    ]).animate(animationController);
    degFourTranslationAnimation = TweenSequence([
      TweenSequenceItem<double>(
          tween: Tween<double>(begin: 0.0, end: 2.10), weight: 15.0),
      TweenSequenceItem<double>(
          tween: Tween<double>(begin: 2.10, end: 1.0), weight: 85.0),
    ]).animate(animationController);
    rotationAnimation = Tween<double>(begin: 180.0, end: 0.0).animate(
        CurvedAnimation(parent: animationController, curve: Curves.easeOut));
    super.initState();
    animationController.addListener(() {
      setState(() {});
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Test page'),
      ),
      body: ListView.separated(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
        itemCount: 50,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return Container(
            height: 50,
            color: Colors.blue,
            child: Center(child: Text('Entry ${index}')),
          );
        },
        separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) => const Divider(),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          Positioned(
              right: 30,
              bottom: 30,
              child: Stack(
                alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
                children: <Widget>[
                  IgnorePointer(
                    child: Container(
                      color: Colors.white.withOpacity(
                          0.0), // comment or change to transparent color
                      height: 150.0,
                      width: 150.0,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Transform.translate(
                    offset: Offset.fromDirection(getRadiansFromDegree(270),
                        degOneTranslationAnimation.value * 100),
                    child: Transform(
                      transform: Matrix4.rotationZ(
                          getRadiansFromDegree(rotationAnimation.value))
                        ..scale(degOneTranslationAnimation.value),
                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                      child: CircularButton(
                        color: Colors.red,
                        width: 40,
                        height: 40,
                        icon: Icon(
                          Icons.add,
                          color: Colors.white,
                        ),
                        onClick: () {
                          print('First Button');
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Transform.translate(
                    offset: Offset.fromDirection(getRadiansFromDegree(240),
                        degTwoTranslationAnimation.value * 100),
                    child: Transform(
                      transform: Matrix4.rotationZ(
                          getRadiansFromDegree(rotationAnimation.value))
                        ..scale(degTwoTranslationAnimation.value),
                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                      child: CircularButton(
                        color: Colors.black54,
                        width: 40,
                        height: 40,
                        icon: Icon(
                          Icons.shop_two,
                          color: Colors.white,
                        ),
                        onClick: () {
                          print('Second button');
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Transform.translate(
                    offset: Offset.fromDirection(getRadiansFromDegree(210),
                        degThreeTranslationAnimation.value * 100),
                    child: Transform(
                      transform: Matrix4.rotationZ(
                          getRadiansFromDegree(rotationAnimation.value))
                        ..scale(degThreeTranslationAnimation.value),
                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                      child: CircularButton(
                        color: Colors.black54,
                        width: 40,
                        height: 40,
                        icon: Icon(
                          Icons.equalizer,
                          color: Colors.white,
                        ),
                        onClick: () {
                          print('Third Button');
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Transform.translate(
                    offset: Offset.fromDirection(getRadiansFromDegree(180),
                        degFourTranslationAnimation.value * 100),
                    child: Transform(
                      transform: Matrix4.rotationZ(
                          getRadiansFromDegree(rotationAnimation.value))
                        ..scale(degFourTranslationAnimation.value),
                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                      child: CircularButton(
                        color: Colors.black54,
                        width: 40,
                        height: 40,
                        icon: Icon(
                          Icons.settings,
                          color: Colors.white,
                        ),
                        onClick: () {
                          print('Fourth Button');
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Transform(
                    transform: Matrix4.rotationZ(
                        getRadiansFromDegree(rotationAnimation.value)),
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    child: CircularButton(
                      color: Colors.red,
                      width: 60,
                      height: 60,
                      icon: Icon(
                        Icons.menu,
                        color: Colors.white,
                      ),
                      onClick: () {
                        if (animationController.isCompleted) {
                          animationController.reverse();
                        } else {
                          animationController.forward();
                        }
                      },
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ))
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class CircularButton extends StatelessWidget {
  final double width;
  final double height;
  final Color color;
  final Icon icon;
  final Function onClick;

  CircularButton(
      {this.color, this.width, this.height, this.icon, this.onClick});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(color: color, shape: BoxShape.circle),
      width: width,
      height: height,
      child: IconButton(icon: icon, enableFeedback: true, onPressed: onClick),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Is the list view the best widget to use to display videos being pulled from fire base?